# Performance Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an application(an user interface to configure Oven) which is designed with CSS, Java Script, Jquery & Json . My Client complains that the user interface performs the actions in a milliseconds in any browser or on their simulator but whereas in a real time device (i.e., in oven) it takes seconds to complete it.

Application Details:

•         This application has very limited features like Settings, service and few more to it. Also this is touch screen based application.
•         This application is created using HTML, CSS, Java Script, Jquery technologies and also images.
•         IDE - NetBeans
•         Processor - Arm9
•         RAM - 64 MB 
•         Screen Size - 480 * 800
•         Device Operating System – Linux

I can not produce the code here as it's very large.

What I can do to increase the performance in the real device(i.e Oven)?

Comment: Oven has probably 500Mhz processor maximum, so it will be slow with jQuery. As well Chrome for example is very well optimized. So it depends what kind of JavaScript engine is running on oven.

Comment: PKA, we can't help you optimize something we can't take a look at. But then again, what are you doing that makes any processor work for __seconds__ on some JS that's supposed to configure an oven?

Comment: just a hint, but the more animations you'd have there, the more performance hit you'll encounter - if nothing else can be done, remove any animations and see if that helps for a start

Comment: Try optimizing jQuery by switching to something smaller like zepto, or better ... if you are sure that it will only work on one specific browser it's best for you to write it in pure javascript ( since there will be no need for multi-browser targeting ). I know that this sounds very hard, but it's not a big work if your browser supports modern APIs

Comment: Have you tried using some web debugging/profiling tools like "Profiles" tab in ChromeBug or Profiler in IE Developers tools? There is also an online tool - WebPagetest (I wrote an article about it - http://byteloom.blogspot.com/2012/03/webpagetest-distributed-web-profiler.html). If you put some profiling info here maybe we could find some clue?

Comment: Guys, Thank you all . I will work on your suggestions & will reply back to you. But I want to make one thing clear that this application(User Interface) is not intended for browsers, it's only for the device(Oven).

Answer (score 3):

This happens because when you are using the development interface the data is accessed from local machine, which is relatively faster, also the caching is a big factor, I can't tell you how to decrease json response time without seeing your code but you can use minifiers to reduce the size of javascript, css and html files

```
For Javascript- http://www.jsmini.com/
For HTML- http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/
For CSS- https://csscompressor.net
```

If you want to know why you should use minifiers then I'd suggest you to read

```
http://engineeredweb.com/blog/why-minify-javascript/
```

Comment: I personaly use and recommend this one - YUI Compressor http://yui.github.com/yuicompressor (command line in build scripts as part of build & automatic deployment process)

Comment: Thanks shobit for your answer. I will try this & test it with the real device. Looks like it will work, but due to some confidentiality issue I can't reproduce the code here.

Btw Can you plese give me some tips for how to decrese the json response  time ?

Comment: @Marek :Thank you.. it's really a good Compressor

Comment: @Shobit : Does Compressing Html/css/JavaScript code optimizes the performance of application??

Comment: The blank spaces in HTML/CSS/JS increases the size of the file which increases page load time, so yes, it does optimize the performance